# How to take a string, search for a certain character, and return a string with everything before the character?

Tags: java

I'm a bit new to programming, and for an in class project, I have to take a user-inputted email, find everything before the @ symbol, and return it as a username. The part I'm having trouble on is finding the characters before the @, with it being variable length. As far as I can tell, most methods rely on a preset string length.

[My current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5734D.png)

Comment: I would suggest using two methods of the String class, `indexOf` and `substring`.  Use `indexOf` to find the position of the `@` character, and then `substring` to grab just the first portion of the string based on that position. Since you're processing user input you'll want to allow for the case where the user didn't enter a valid email address and so `indexOf('@')` returns `-1`.  Your code will throw an exception if you blindy try to use that value.

Comment: Please do not post a picture of code. It’s hard to read and prevents our sight impaired users from participating.  Also it cannot be searched or copied into a text editor.  Consider editing your question and pasting the code directly into it as text.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [javadoc of String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html). Of particular interest are `substring` and `indexOf`. It's.. a trivial assignment, there's nothing left to say except spoonfeed you the answer, which probably doesn't help you accomplish the goal (which is, surely, to learn java).

Comment: Ha!  Were we on the same page, or what?!?!